# Apply a function over a column in a group in PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, pyarrow

I have a PySpark dataframe like this,

```
+----------+--------+---------+
|id_       | p      |   a     |
+----------+--------+---------+
|  1       | 4      |   12    |
|  1       | 3      |   14    |
|  1       | -7     |   16    |
|  1       | 5      |   11    |
|  1       | -20    |   90    |
|  1       | 5      |   120   |
|  2       |  11    |   267   |
|  2       | -98    |   124   |
|  2       | -87    |   120   |
|  2       | -1     |   44    |
|  2       |  5     |   1     |
|  2       |  7     |   23    |
-------------------------------
```

I also have a python function like this,

```
def fun(x):
    total = 0
    result = np.empty_like(x)
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        total += (y)
        if total < 0:
            total = 0
        result[i] = total

    return result
```

I want to group the PySpark dataframe on column `id_` and apply the functon `fun` over the column `p`.

I want to something like

```
spark_df.groupBy('id_')['p'].apply(fun)
```

I am currently doing this with a pandas udf with the help of `pyarrow`, which is not efficient in terms of time for my application.

The result I am looking for is,

```
[4, 7, 0, 5, 0, 5, 11, -98, -87, -1, 5, 7]
```

This is resultant dataframe I am looking for,

```
+----------+--------+---------+
|id_       | p      |   a     |
+----------+--------+---------+
|  1       | 4      |   12    |
|  1       | 7      |   14    |
|  1       | 0      |   16    |
|  1       | 5      |   11    |
|  1       | 0      |   90    |
|  1       | 5      |   120   |
|  2       |  11    |   267   |
|  2       | 0      |   124   |
|  2       | 0      |   120   |
|  2       | 0      |   44    |
|  2       |  5     |   1     |
|  2       |  12    |   23    |
-------------------------------
```

Is there a direct way to do this with pyspark APIs itself.?

I can aggregate and column `p` to a list using `collect_list` on grouping on `id_` and use `udf` over that and use `explode` to get the column `p` as I needed in the result dataframe.

But how to retain other columns that I have in my dataframe.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve the result I need with the following steps,

My DataFrame looks like this,

```
+---+---+---+
|id_|  p|  a|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  4| 12|
|  1|  3| 14|
|  1| -7| 16|
|  1|  5| 11|
|  1|-20| 90|
|  1|  5|120|
|  2| 11|267|
|  2|-98|124|
|  2|-87|120|
|  2| -1| 44|
|  2|  5|  1|
|  2|  7| 23|
+---+---+---+
```

I will groupby the dataframe on `id_` and collect the column I want to apply the function to a list using `collect_list` and apply the function like this,

```
agg_df = df.groupBy('id_').agg(F.collect_list('p').alias('collected_p'))
agg_df = agg_df.withColumn('new', fun('collected_p'))
```

I now want to somehow merge `agg_df` to my original dataframe. For that I will first use explode to get the values in column `new` in rows.

```
agg_df = agg_df.withColumn('exploded', F.explode('new'))
```

In order to merge I will use `monotonically_increasing_id` to generate `id` for the original dataframe and  `agg_df`. From that I will make `idx` for each dataframe because `monotonically_increasing_id` won't be same for both dataframes.

```
agg_df = agg_df.withColumn('id_mono', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df = df.withColumn('id_mono', F.monotonically_increasing_id())

w = Window().partitionBy(F.lit(0)).orderBy('id_mono')

df = df.withColumn('idx', F.row_number().over(w))
agg_df = agg_df.withColumn('idx', F.row_number().over(w))

df = df.join(agg_df.select('idx', 'exploded'), ['idx']).drop('id_mono', 'idx')


+---+---+---+--------+
|id_|  p|  a|exploded|
+---+---+---+--------+
|  1|  4| 12|       4|
|  1|  3| 14|       7|
|  1| -7| 16|       0|
|  1|  5| 11|       5|
|  1|-20| 90|       0|
|  1|  5|120|       5|
|  2| 11|267|      11|
|  2|-98|124|       0|
|  2|-87|120|       0|
|  2| -1| 44|       0|
|  2|  5|  1|       5|
|  2|  7| 23|      12|
+---+---+---+--------+
```

I am not sure this is a straight forward way to do. It will be great if anyone can suggest any optimizations for this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can convert the above python function to a Pyspark UDF.
Since you are returning an array of integers, it is important to specify the return type as `ArrayType(IntegerType())`.

Below is the code,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType, collect_list

@udf(returnType=ArrayType(IntegerType()))
def fun(x):
    total = 0
    result = np.empty_like(x)
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        total += (y)
        if total < 0:
            total = 0
        result[i] = total
    return result.tolist()    # Convert NumPy Array to Python List
```

Since the input to your `udf` must be a list, let's group the data based on 'id' and convert the rows to arrays.

```
df = df.groupBy('id_').agg(collect_list('p'))
df = df.toDF('id_', 'p_')    # Assign a new alias name 'p_'
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Input Data:

```
+---+------------------------+
|id_|collect_list(p)         |
+---+------------------------+
|1  |[4, 3, -7, 5, -20, 5]   |
|2  |[11, -98, -87, -1, 5, 7]|
+---+------------------------+
```

Next, we apply the `udf` on this data,

```
df.select('id_', fun(df.p_)).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------------+
|id_|fun(p_)             |
+---+--------------------+
|1  |[4, 7, 0, 5, 0, 5]  |
|2  |[11, 0, 0, 0, 5, 12]|
+---+--------------------+
```

Comment: But what I want is something the output to be in a column. I can use explode for that I guess. See the updated Q for the expected dataframe